# Can you save a file on the local drive through RemoteApp instead of saving to server drives?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog, remoteapp

I have an application written in C# WPF, and saving a generated Word document. Through the RemoteApp settings, I've set to show the local user's logical drives, but they don't have letters next to them. They show up as `C on myHostname`, `D on myHostname`, etc.

When I open up a `SaveFileDialog` object, it shows `Local Disk (C:)`, `C on myHostname`, and `D on myHostname` in the left-hand pane.

How do I set the filename, if there's no corresponding letter?

```
string filename = @"C:\myDirectory\myFile.docx";
using(WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
    WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, 
        WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I'm using Terminal Services Client, I can use the keyword `tsclient` to tell it to use the local user's drives.

```
// Check if remote session, and get the local drive location
if(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession) {
    filename = @"\\tsclient\C\myDirectory\myFile.docx";
}
```