# Using OpenFileDialog to get files of client in RDP

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, openfiledialog, rdp

For some software i have been using RDP files to run them.

### RDP Files

Those who don't know what RDP file is it is a small file that acts as a **gateway between a server and client machine** which instead of showing the whole desktop shows you just the application which is connected with the RDP.

### Problem

When i use **OpenFileDialog** it gives me the files of the server machine but here i want the files to be shown of client's PC.

### Note

For sharing drive details of client i have already enabled the option. If you want to know how it looks like here are the steps:-

1. Go to "Run" -> type "mstsc" -> press enter
2. a box appears click "Show Options" -> go to "Local Resources" tab
3. under "Local device and resources" -> click "More" -> and enable everything

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any provision in RDP file to expose the clients directory in server ?  Normally when we do remote desktop, we can configure this .. thats why

Comment: yes there is an option to do so which i have already enabled but i don't know how to use them?

Comment: Are you running application with administrative privilege? If not can you try with that ?

Comment: i have tried with both but it is of no use because the software is commanded to take resources of the residing machine which is the server but i want the resources of client.

Comment: Looks like something is missing in your configuration. Someone able to access/show the files in the open file dialog..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570989/can-you-save-a-file-on-the-local-drive-through-remoteapp-instead-of-saving-to-se

Comment: @Venkatesh i found where can i fix it with your post. Thanks please post the comment in the answer section.

Comment: You can include the changes you did to resolve so that which may help someone(including me:)).

Comment: sorry, but i cannot post my solution because this solution leads me to another question which i will post once my 90 min. stackoverflow question timer expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is missing in your configuration. Someone able to access/show the files in the open file dialog. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570989/can-you-save-a-file-on-the-local-drive-through-remoteapp-instead-of-saving-to-se)